# If a web component is not rendering properly, what are some good ways to help debug?

Tags: lit-element

I have a web component that renders properly when I load the page the first time. However, when I try to render it the second time, it doesn't load at all. What are some good ways to debug lit web components to see why its not loading properly.

What I see in the dom is the following:

```
<element><div></div></element>
```

It's missing all the html inside the div.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal repro using the https://lit.dev/playground, or share more about the environment you're in. Often if the contents are not rendered within the element, the element has not been defined on the browser custom element registry. Check that `customElements.get('my-element')` is not null.